# Disable a secondary submit button until a new search is done

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search page that returns a list of items.  You can run a new search on the page.  I have a feature to save the search you just ran using a simple form.  That form has a submit button too.

If a user searches for something and then saves the search, I want to disable the button on the save-search form until they run a new search.

Anyone have a rough fiddle with something similar that I can get ideas from on how to accomplish that?  I can run on pure js, jQuery, or related bootstrap if that would help garner any ideas.

I am no js expert so I learn best by example.

Comment: Unfortunately `learn best by example` more often than not implies `please code this for me` which is not the purpose of this site. It is on you to make attempts and provide code that you are having specific problems with

Comment: Ya I get that - sorry wasn't my intent.  I am more JAVA/JSP developer and SQL, Unix subs, etc but you know how it is, these days you have to know how to integrate everything.  I get a little fuddled with javascript but am starting to really appreciate it the value of it on so many levels.

Comment: yeah that's cool...would get more attention with a small statement like that in question along with at least a hack attempt

Answer (score 0):

Just as short example following [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/ha37oen6/)

```
$("#save").click(function () {
  $("#submit").unbind("click");
});
$("#submit").click(submit);
 $("#search").click(function () {
   $("#submit").bind("click", function () {
     submit();
   });
 });

function submit() {
  alert("Submit");
}
```

HTML

```
<input id="save" value="Save" type="submit" />
<input id="submit" value="Submit" type="submit" />
<input id="search" value="Search" type="submit" />
```

This is just an approach using jQuery-functions [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)  and [unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) - if `save` is clicked, the `submit()`-function is removed from the `click`-event of `submit`. If `search` is clicked, the `submit()`-function get's bound to the `submit`-button again.